# Removing UTMStack Agent from Linux

Tags: utm

When testing with UTMStack, I was wanting to remove the Linux agent off an Ubuntu server. I'm only seeing in the documentation on installing it, but not removing it. What would be the correct commands to do so?

Thank you

Comment: Open the installer script with your favourite text editor. Do the reverse of the install commands.

Comment: Or just revert to the snapshot you took of the server before testing it. You did take a snapshot, right?

Comment: The installer when opening it up is just garbled text and symbols. Nothing to really parse commands from.

Comment: Now you learned the lesson of not testing anything on a production server.

Answer (score 0):

just run the installer without nothing more, that’s all.

cd /opt/linux-agent/

./utmstack-linux

Regards,

Mr.Brown

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Said it wasn't a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's hard and dirty way to go.

Make a new VM and snapshot a list of files (with checksums). Then install UTMStack Agent and compare the list with the previous one. This will shed the light on what it installed and what it modified, so you can guess which actions are needed to revert those changes.